# How does App Store Connect define active devices?

Tags: ios, analytics

to check my iOS App Analytics I checked here
 https://analytics.itunes.apple.com/ I found a different analytics. I am interested on the active devices so I saw this analytic

[image]

but I don't know how App analytics define an active device, does it considers each device whose application is launched as an active device? or the application must be open for a specific duration. or is there any other condition for the device to be considered an active device

thank you

Answer (score 1):

There's a little tooltip next to Active Devices on the main metrics screen.

```
The total number of devices with at least one session during the selected period.
```